# How to make a column based on another column's value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a column called `code` This column contains 2 letter values. What I want to do is create another column called `with_j` and in that column I want all codes that end with j. However, instead of it saying the actual code, I want this: `*j`

So something that looks like this:

**Before:**

```
code
bx
aj
dj
la
```

**After**

```
code   with_j
bx
aj     *j
dj     *j
la
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually very simple with `endsWith` and `when/otherwise`.

```
Seq("bx", "aj", "dj", "la")
    .toDF("code")
    .withColumn("with_j", 
        when('code endsWith "j", "*j").otherwise("")
    )
    .show
```